# Switch user via command line (including password input)

Tags: linux, centos

Due to some bad files / permission management, there is a script on our CentOS 7 server that can only run under a certain user (let's call him `user_1`. We all know that user's password (it's sort of a common user - don't ask, long story).

Now - we need to run that script via a CRON that is setup for another user (`user_2`). What I'm looking for is along the lines of (pseudo-code):

```
changeuser user_1 password ; bash script.sh
```

Neither of the two users is `root` and I don't want to do this as `root`. Is this even possible?

Comment: Why not set up something like `sudo` to manage this sort of privilege escalation? You could configure passwordless access from `user_2` to `user_1` for just that script.

Comment: @larsks - we're low on (good) sysadmin support, so when I posted the question I was not aware of the option you mentioned. However, I have to ask for step by step instruction as server management is not exactly my strong suit.